# Flutter Container Slide

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isContainerExpanded = false;
  double _containerHeight = 300;
  double _dragStart = 0;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _toggleContainerSize() {
    setState(() {
      _isContainerExpanded = !_isContainerExpanded;
      if (_isContainerExpanded) {
        _animationController.forward(from: 0);
        _containerHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85;
      } else {
        _animationController.reverse(from: 1);
        _containerHeight = 350;
      }
    });
  }

  void _updateContainerHeight(double dragDistance) {
    double newHeight = _containerHeight + dragDistance;
    newHeight =
        newHeight.clamp(250.0, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85);
    setState(() {
      _containerHeight = newHeight;
    });
  }

  void _onVerticalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (_containerHeight > MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6) {
      _toggleContainerSize();
    } else {
      _toggleContainerSize();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color(0xffF4E0F2),
                  Color(0xffF4E0F2),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.topRight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  (FontAwesomeIcons.wallet),
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              Text(
                "Hesap",
                style: GoogleFonts.cormorant(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 28,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xffF4E0F2),
                    Colors.white,
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 50,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Center(child: MoneyCard()),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onVerticalDragStart: (details) {
                            _dragStart = details.globalPosition.dy;
                          },
                          onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                            double dragDistance =
                                _dragStart - details.globalPosition.dy;
                            _dragStart = details.globalPosition.dy;
                            _updateContainerHeight(dragDistance);
                          },
                          onVerticalDragEnd: _onVerticalDragEnd,
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                            height: _containerHeight,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                            ),
                            child: ListView(
                              controller: _scrollController,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              physics: _isContainerExpanded
                                  ? AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
                                  : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    const Divider(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      thickness: 3,
                                      indent: 80,
                                      endIndent: 80,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                                    Text(
                                      "Geçmiş İşlemler",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.cormorant(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 15),
                                CustomListCard(),
                                CustomListCard(),
                                CustomListCard(),
                                CustomListCard(),
                                CustomListCard(),
                                CustomListCard(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomListCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 0.6,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255), // Arka plan rengi
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          // BorderRadius uygulamak için ClipRRect kullanıyoruz
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),

          child: SizedBox(
            height: 95,
            width: 45,
            child: ListTile(
              tileColor: Colors
                  .transparent, // ListTile'ın arka plan rengi şeffaf olmalı
              title: Row(
                // Burada Row widget'ını kullanarak simgeyi sola alıyoruz
                children: [
                  const Icon(
                    (FontAwesomeIcons.clock),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Text(
                    "17.43",
                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoCondensed(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              subtitle: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    // Metinleri sola hizalamak için Row widget'ını kullanıyoruz.
                    mainAxisAlignment:
                        MainAxisAlignment.start, // Metinleri sola hizalar.
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                          width:
                              8), // Sol boşluk eklemek için SizedBox kullanıyoruz.
                      Text(
                        "X Firma",
                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: Colors.grey[800],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    // Metinleri sola hizalamak için Row widget'ını kullanıyoruz.
                    mainAxisAlignment:
                        MainAxisAlignment.start, // Metinleri sola hizalar.
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                          width:
                              8), // Sol boşluk eklemek için SizedBox kullanıyoruz.
                      Text(
                        'Satılan ürünün ilk ay ödemesi',
                        style: GoogleFonts.robotoCondensed(
                          textStyle:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              trailing: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "+ 11258 TL",
                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoCondensed(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 4),
                  Text(
                    "",
                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoCondensed(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can the Container with a ListView inside be smoothly expanded and collapsed, similar to a drawer, without [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGm1j.png)relying on clicks? When the Container is pulled upwards, it should automatically reach a specified size, and when pulled downwards, it should smoothly return to its original state.

"I have implemented the animation for the Container to expand and shrink smoothly. When clicked, the Container automatically enlarges and then automatically shrinks."

"When the Container is growing, it works very well. In the small state, I set 'scroll' to false, so there is no issue while it's growing. However, when it needs to shrink, I have to keep 'scroll' active in the larger Container, which makes it impossible to shrink properly. Is there a part in my approach that needs to be fixed, or is there a general suggestion that this code usage is incorrect?"

Comment: I think it won't work smoothly because you are trying to have scrolling behavior in the inner widget that matches the scroll direction of the outer `Scrollable` widget.

Comment: "When the Container is growing, it works very well. In the small state, I set 'scroll' to false, so there is no issue while it's growing. However, when it needs to shrink, I have to keep 'scroll' active in the larger Container, which makes it impossible to shrink properly. Is there a part in my approach that needs to be fixed, or is there a general suggestion that this code usage is incorrect?"